# a static variable in c

Tags: c, static

Hi
I'm studying for my test in C and i've encountered a question which i can't figure its answer.

A programmer wrote a program to count number of users (Count.h, Count.c):

```
/******** FILE: Counter.h ***********/
static int counter = 0;
int getUsersNum ();
/******** END OF FILE: Counter.h ****/

/******** FILE: Counter.c ***********/
#include "Counter.h"
int getUsersNum ()
{
    return counter;
}
/******** END OF FILE: Counter.c ****/
```

And a tester to test it:

```
/******** FILE: CounterMain.c ***********/
#include "Counter.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        ++counter;
        printf ("Users num:  %d\n", getUsersNum());
    }
    return 0;
}
/******** END OF FILE: CounterMain.c ****/
```

Suprisingly the output was:

```
Users num: 0
Users num: 0
Users num: 0
Users num: 0
Users num: 0
```

I can't see why with this use of static variable the counter does not advance.. why did they get such input?

thank you all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just think of it as ".h files don't exist". What happens is that the .h files are included inside the .c files and only the .c files get compiled (and linked (mixed) together).

In your case you have 2 .c files with

```
static int counter = 0;
```

Each `counter` is specific to the .c file it is in. The `counter` in CounterMain.c is a different variable than the `counter` in Counter.c.

You need to have **one** single **definition** of counter. You can have several declarations (typically in .h files)

```
/* .h file */
extern int counter;

/* .c file(s) that use the counter but don't define it */
#include "file.h"

/* .c file that **defines** counter */
#include "file.h"
int counter = 0;
```

---

**Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh** and there's the `static` thing. Don't use it at global scope!

Comment: +1 for posting a simple explaination and solution instead of going through lots of accurate, but gory details.

Answer (score 14):

In C, the scope of a static variable is the source file in which its defined.

Since you're loading this header into 2 separate .c files, each file gets a unique variable.  Incrementing "counter" in one file does not affect the "static" variable in the other file.

For details, see [this description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable).  In order for the variable to be visible and shared in multiple files, it needs to be declared as extern.  Otherwise:

> Static global variables: variables declared as static at the top level of a source file (outside any function definitions) are visible throughout that file ("file scope").

Which is the case here.

Comment: "Source file" is confusing because a header file is a source file and the variable is only declared in one source file. _Translation unit_ would be more accurate.

Comment: `In C, the scope of a static variable is the source file in which its defined`. You might want to replace `source file` with `translation unit`.

Comment: @Charles : Too quick! I was posting exactly the same thing. :D

Comment: @Prasoon and @Charles: That was a direct quotation, not my text.  That was why I specifically mentioned ".c files" in my answer..

Comment: @Prasoon: While "translation unit" is correct, it's not going to be as obvious to the original poster...

Comment: It may not be obvious and it may need explaining but I think that it's necessary to use the concept of a translation unit to explain the behaviour whether or not you use the correct technical term. Using the term "source file" loosely is likely to be more confusing IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

A C program is made by combining one or more *translation units* together to make a program.

A *translation unit* is, in effect, a preprocessed source file. It contains any included header and source files specified in `#include` directives, and excludes anything excluded by `#if` or similar directives.

When a variable at file scope is declared `static` it gives the variable name *internal linkage*. This means that the name refers to an object local to the translation unit in which it appears. If the name is used in another translation unit then it cannot refer to the object in this translation unit, it must refer to a different object.

[In contrast, a name with external linkage refers to the same object whatever translation unit the name is used in.]

```
static int counter = 0;
```

When you put a declaration such as this in a header file, it means that every translation unit that includes the header file has its own unique object called `counter` that is distinct from any object called `counter` in any other translation unit.

In your case there is one `counter` in the translation unit generated from `CounterMain.c` and a separate one in the translation unit generate from `Count.c`. The one in `Count.c` is never incremented but is returned by `getUserNum()`, the one in `CounterMain.c` is incremented in `main` but never used anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The `static` keyword means, when used to qualify functions or global variables, that the  function or variable should have `internal linkage`, meaning it shouldn't be visible as a global symbol. Therefore, each compilation unit including `Counter.h` will have its own local copy of `counter` which won't clash with others.

In this case, `Counter.c` and `CounterMain.c` have different variables `count`, resulting in what you have described.

The solution is to change the definition of `counter` in `Counter.h` to a declaration:
`extern int counter;`
and to put the definition in `Counter.c`:
`int counter = 0;`

Afterwards `CounterMain` and any other compilation units including `Counter.h` should be able to access the single instance `counter`, but you may want to indulge in `information hiding` and only access it through functions in `Counter`, resulting in a cleaner `interface`.

Comment: How is `static` different for functions and variabls?

Comment: @Charles Bailey It's different once you delve down into the generated code, but if you look only at the C level, it's semantically pretty much the same.

Comment: It's not for functions and global variables: It changes the linkage as I've explained (I've edited my answer to read "variable or function"). With simple local variables, it means "static storage and lifetime", i.e. a plain old static variable.

Comment: You mean it has a different meaning when applied to objects with block scope as opposed to when applied to functions and objects with file scope. Your first sentence is ambiguous as you don't say what context you are comparing against when saying "has a different meaning".

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Fixed.

Comment: Actually I was planning on just linking to another question which explained the different usages of `static`, but just couldn't find a good one.

Comment: I'm going to sound pedantic now and it's not important because it's not central to the original question but saying that `static` applied to local variables makes them `static` is circular and doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: How did I know you'd say that? :) Removed all references to the other usage.

Answer (score 2):

`static int counter = 0;`

If a variable has been defined using the static storage class specifier the variable has an [**internal linkage**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr081.htm). That means you can use `counter` inside the same [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) in which it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

A `static` variable is only accessible in the file in which it's defined. In this example, `Counter.c` and `CounterMain.c` both have their own `counter` variable.

When `++counter` is executed, this updates the variable declared in `CounterMain.c`. But when `getUsersNum()` is called, this returns the value of the `counter` variable from `Counter.c`, which hasn't been incremented.

If you change `getUsersNum()` to `counter`, you'll see the `counter` variable declared in `CounterMain.c` has been incremented.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the static variable is declared in the header. In C, static variables exist only in the **.c** file in which they're declared. Since your .h is included (`#include` directives can be seen as nothing more than a copy-paste operation) in two distinct .c files, two static variables named `counter` are created, one in each file. Your test file increments its local `counter` variable, but the one returned by `getUsersNum` is from another C file and is completely independent.

What the question tries to do is access a static variable from a file other than the one in which it was declared. You should know that it's not (directly) possible. To increment the right counter, you will need a function that operates on *Counter.c*'s `counter` variable.